# Java Selenium 3.3.1 and geckodriver 0.15.0 not waiting on windows 10

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver

Anyone else having problems with the above?
I can't seem to get geckodriver to wait at all either implicitly or explicitly. It only works when I use Thread.sleep()

Here is my Explicit method which works fine throughout my code base with the chromedriver:

```
public void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver driver) throws MyTestException {
    try { new WebDriverWait(driver, page_timeout).until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) wd ->
        ((JavascriptExecutor) wd).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"));
        } catch (Exception e){logger.warning("Waiting for page load failed.");}
}
```

I'm not even having to use an implicit call.

Here is my gecko driver init code where I also init an implicit wait.

```
else if (config.useFirefox()) { 

            String geckoDriverLocation = config.getProperty("qa.webdriverpath") + "geckodriver.exe";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", geckoDriverLocation);
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        }
```

Without using a sleep, its not even waiting for login elements to fill.
Example:

```
    WebElement emailText = test.getDriver().findElement(By.name("email"));
    WebElement passText = test.getDriver().findElement(By.name("password"));
    WebElement loginButton = test.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));
    test.getLogger().info("Logging in as user " + user.contact.getName() + " (" + user.getEmail() + ")...");
    emailText.clear();
    emailText.click();
    emailText.sendKeys(user.getEmail());
    emailText.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

    passText.clear();
    passText.sendKeys(user.getPassword());
    passText.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);

    loginButton.click();

    //try{Thread.sleep(3000);}catch(Exception e){}
    test.waitForPageLoad(test.getDriver());
```

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: So, you are getting NoSuchElementException for elements when using geckodriver? Or how do you determine that implicit wait doesn'w work?

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same issue with selenium 3.3.1, geckodriver 0.15.0 and Firefox 52.0.2. The implicit wait is not working. Workaround is to keep adding sleep but that is bad. I found this bug already raised https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/308

Comment: I was using selenium 3.1 with geckodirver .14.0 on a mac about 45 days ago and it was working fine (although it would not close web pages). Not sure whats up now. I'm actually running into lots of errors with it.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit wait works fine in geckodriver, but page load time out doesn't work in geckodriver, it is a bug in geckdriver and it was raised. So Please use Legacy fire fox driver, it works pretty well.

Page time out doesn't work means, After you click a button, it doesn't wait for page to load completely, it releases the control immediately after the click.

Install Fire fox 47.0.2(That's the last version legacy firefox driver can drive)

If you use selenium webdriver 3.3.0 then geckodriver is the default one so to deactive geckodriver, you just make the parameter marionette false!

This is the way I use in Ruby selenium binding to make marionette to false

```
caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(marionette: false)
```

Please find the corresponding one to Java.

Comment: Yeah, I get an endless stack trace of crashes if I try that. I'm on firefox 52. Basically thats a no driver found issue.